# Cannot use AWS SSO credentials with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-cdk

Since PR: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/19454 and release [v2.18.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v2.18.0) CDK is supposed to support SSO credentials via the AWS CLI v2 profiles.

However no matter what I do I simply cannot get this to work.
I have created a request for updated documentation in the AWS CDK Issues section, since no official documentation explains how this is supposed to function in practice, and the official documentation still saying it is not supported and to use yawsso: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/21314

From going through 4 years of old threads to now I have attempted the following settings with 0 success.
My `.aws/config` file (sensitive values redacted):

```
[profile DEV-NN-HSMX]
sso_start_url = https://my-company-url.awsapps.com/start#/
sso_region = eu-central-1
sso_account_name = MY-ACCOUNT
sso_account_id = MY-ACCOUNT-ID
sso_role_name = AdministratorAccess
region = eu-central-1
```

Running `aws sso login --profile "DEV-NN-HSMX"` redirects me as expected and I can authenticate with my SSO provider.
Running `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile "DEV-NN-HSMX"` works as expected and confirms my SSO identity.
Running  `aws s3 ls --profile "DEV-NN-HSMX"` works as expected and shows that the credentials have access.

When attempting to run any CDK commands however. I simply cannot make it work.

AWS CLI version: 2.7.16
AWS CDK version: 2.33.0

I have attempted a combination of all the following, either separately, mixed in all combinations and all at once.
`cdk deploy --profile "DEV-NN-HSMX"`

Exporting both the `$AWS_PROFILE` and/or the `$CDK_DEFAULT_PROFILE` environment variables:

```
cdk doctor
ℹ️ CDK Version: 2.33.0 (build 859272d)
ℹ️ AWS environment variables:
  - AWS_CA_BUNDLE = /home/vscode/certs/cacert.pem
  - AWS_PROFILE = DEV-NN-HSMX
  - AWS_REGION = eu-central-1
  - AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS = regional
  - AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED = 1
  - AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG = 1
ℹ️ CDK environment variables:
  - CDK_DEFAULT_PROFILE = DEV-NN-HSMX
  - CDK_DEFAULT_REGION = eu-central-1
```

I have tried with a deleted `.aws/credentials` file as well as one that is just empty.
I have deleted everything in `aws\sso\cache` and in `.aws\cli\cache` to make sure no expired credential information remained and then re-authenticated with `aws sso login --profile "DEV-NN-HSMX"`.

If I use `yawsso --profiles DEV-NN-HSMX` and get temporary credentials into `.aws/credentials` for my profile, it works fine.

I have been able to bootstrap and deploy without issues using the credential conversion. Proving that from a connection, access rights and bootstrap standpoint everything works as expected.

When using any of the SSO methods as explained above without exporting credentials, I always get the following error message.

```
cdk deploy --profile "DEV-NN-HSMX"

✨  Synthesis time: 4.18s
Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment
```

Running the command with full verbosity gives this output:

```
cdk deploy --trace --verbose --profile "DEV-NN-HSMX"
CDK toolkit version: 2.33.0 (build 859272d)
Command line arguments: {
  _: [ 'deploy' ],
  trace: true,
  verbose: 1,
  v: 1,
  profile: 'DEV-NN-HSMX',
  defaultProfile: 'DEV-NN-HSMX',
  defaultRegion: 'eu-central-1',
  lookups: true,
  'ignore-errors': false,
  ignoreErrors: false,
  json: false,
  j: false,
  debug: false,
  ec2creds: undefined,
  i: undefined,
  'version-reporting': undefined,
  versionReporting: undefined,
  'path-metadata': true,
  pathMetadata: true,
  'asset-metadata': true,
  assetMetadata: true,
  'role-arn': undefined,
  r: undefined,
  roleArn: undefined,
  staging: true,
  'no-color': false,
  noColor: false,
  ci: false,
  all: false,
  'build-exclude': [],
  E: [],
  buildExclude: [],
  execute: true,
  force: false,
  f: false,
  parameters: [ {} ],
  'previous-parameters': true,
  previousParameters: true,
  logs: true,
  '$0': '/home/vscode/.local/state/fnm_multishells/216_1658735050827/bin/cdk'
}
cdk.json: {
  "app": "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/cdk-demo.ts",
  "watch": {
    "include": [
      "**"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "README.md",
      "cdk*.json",
      "**/*.d.ts",
      "**/*.js",
      "tsconfig.json",
      "package*.json",
      "yarn.lock",
      "node_modules",
      "test"
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:usagePlanKeyOrderInsensitiveId": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-rds:lowercaseDbIdentifier": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeVersionProps": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeLayerVersion": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront:defaultSecurityPolicyTLSv1.2_2021": true,
    "@aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions:enableDefaultLogDriver": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2:uniqueImdsv2TemplateName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam:minimizePolicies": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:validateSnapshotRemovalPolicy": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline:crossAccountKeyAliasStackSafeResourceName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-s3:createDefaultLoggingPolicy": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions:restrictSqsDescryption": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:target-partitions": [
      "aws",
      "aws-cn"
    ]
  }
}
merged settings: {
  versionReporting: true,
  pathMetadata: true,
  output: 'cdk.out',
  app: 'npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/cdk-demo.ts',
  watch: {
    include: [ '**' ],
    exclude: [
      'README.md',
      'cdk*.json',
      '**/*.d.ts',
      '**/*.js',
      'tsconfig.json',
      'package*.json',
      'yarn.lock',
      'node_modules',
      'test'
    ]
  },
  context: {
    '@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:usagePlanKeyOrderInsensitiveId': true,
    '@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-rds:lowercaseDbIdentifier': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeVersionProps': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeLayerVersion': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront:defaultSecurityPolicyTLSv1.2_2021': true,
    '@aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions:enableDefaultLogDriver': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-ec2:uniqueImdsv2TemplateName': true,
    '@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-iam:minimizePolicies': true,
    '@aws-cdk/core:validateSnapshotRemovalPolicy': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline:crossAccountKeyAliasStackSafeResourceName': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-s3:createDefaultLoggingPolicy': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions:restrictSqsDescryption': true,
    '@aws-cdk/core:target-partitions': [ 'aws', 'aws-cn' ]
  },
  debug: false,
  assetMetadata: true,
  profile: 'DEV-NN-HSMX',
  toolkitBucket: {},
  staging: true,
  bundlingStacks: [ '*' ],
  lookups: true
}
Using CA bundle path: /home/vscode/certs/cacert.pem
Toolkit stack: CDKToolkit
Setting "CDK_DEFAULT_REGION" environment variable to eu-central-1
Resolving default credentials
Could not refresh notices: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
Unable to determine the default AWS account: ProcessCredentialsProviderFailure: Profile DEV-NN-HSMX did not include credential process
    at ProcessCredentials2.load (/home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials/process_credentials.js:102:11)
    at ProcessCredentials2.coalesceRefresh (/home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:205:12)
    at ProcessCredentials2.refresh (/home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials/process_credentials.js:163:10)
    at ProcessCredentials2.get2 [as get] (/home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:122:12)
    at resolveNext2 (/home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials/credential_provider_chain.js:125:17)
    at /home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials/credential_provider_chain.js:126:13
    at /home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:124:23
    at /home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:212:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  code: 'ProcessCredentialsProviderFailure',
  time: 2022-07-25T15:01:41.645Z
}
context: {
  '@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:usagePlanKeyOrderInsensitiveId': true,
  '@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports': true,
  '@aws-cdk/aws-rds:lowercaseDbIdentifier': true,
  '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeVersionProps': true,
  '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeLayerVersion': true,
  '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront:defaultSecurityPolicyTLSv1.2_2021': true,
  '@aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions:enableDefaultLogDriver': true,
  '@aws-cdk/aws-ec2:uniqueImdsv2TemplateName': true,
  '@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage': true,
  '@aws-cdk/aws-iam:minimizePolicies': true,
  '@aws-cdk/core:validateSnapshotRemovalPolicy': true,
  '@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline:crossAccountKeyAliasStackSafeResourceName': true,
  '@aws-cdk/aws-s3:createDefaultLoggingPolicy': true,
  '@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions:restrictSqsDescryption': true,
  '@aws-cdk/core:target-partitions': [ 'aws', 'aws-cn' ],
  'aws:cdk:enable-path-metadata': true,
  'aws:cdk:enable-asset-metadata': true,
  'aws:cdk:version-reporting': true,
  'aws:cdk:bundling-stacks': [ '*' ]
}
outdir: cdk.out
env: {
  CDK_DEFAULT_REGION: 'eu-central-1',
  CDK_CONTEXT_JSON: '{"@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:usagePlanKeyOrderInsensitiveId":true,"@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports":true,"@aws-cdk/aws-rds:lowercaseDbIdentifier":true,"@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeVersionProps":true,"@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeLayerVersion":true,"@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront:defaultSecurityPolicyTLSv1.2_2021":true,"@aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions:enableDefaultLogDriver":true,"@aws-cdk/aws-ec2:uniqueImdsv2TemplateName":true,"@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage":true,"@aws-cdk/aws-iam:minimizePolicies":true,"@aws-cdk/core:validateSnapshotRemovalPolicy":true,"@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline:crossAccountKeyAliasStackSafeResourceName":true,"@aws-cdk/aws-s3:createDefaultLoggingPolicy":true,"@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions:restrictSqsDescryption":true,"@aws-cdk/core:target-partitions":["aws","aws-cn"],"aws:cdk:enable-path-metadata":true,"aws:cdk:enable-asset-metadata":true,"aws:cdk:version-reporting":true,"aws:cdk:bundling-stacks":["*"]}',
  CDK_OUTDIR: 'cdk.out',
  CDK_CLI_ASM_VERSION: '20.0.0',
  CDK_CLI_VERSION: '2.33.0'
}

✨  Synthesis time: 4.54s

Reading existing template for stack CdkDemoStack.
Reading cached notices from /home/vscode/.cdk/cache/notices.json

Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment
Error: Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment
    at SdkProvider.resolveEnvironment (/home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/aws-auth/sdk-provider.ts:238:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.prepareSdkFor (/home/vscode/.local/share/fnm/node-versions/v16.16.0/installation/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:432:33)
```

I do notice the ProcessCredentialsProviderFailure in the output, but this is not very informative on how to solve it.
Anyone have any ideas or input?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like agnostic stacks where you do not put the environment information directly into the stack code does not work with the new SSO integration.

Adding the environment information into the stack code makes it work:

```
const app = new cdk.App();
new CdkDemoStack(app, 'CdkDemoStack', {
  env: { account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, 
         region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION 
       },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem for a few weeks here. The differences for me is this is how my `cdk doctor` command looked:

```
▶ cdk doctor 
ℹ️ CDK Version: 2.99.1 (build b2a895e)
ℹ️ AWS environment variables:
  - AWS_CONFIG_FILE = ~/.aws/config
  - AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS = regional
  - AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED = 1
ℹ️ No CDK environment variables
```

After working with AWS support, I was able to get this working by changing my AWS environment variables such that my new `cdk doctor` result was:

```
▶ cdk doctor 
ℹ️ CDK Version: 2.99.1 (build b2a895e)
ℹ️ AWS environment variables:
  - AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS = regional
  - AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED = 1
  - AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG = 1
ℹ️ No CDK environment variables
```

It looks like you have all of the needed environment variables, but maybe one of your other variables is getting in the way. For example, I had to get rid of the `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable. No guarantees it will work, but it could be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by manually running `aws sso login`.  CDK does not currently refresh sso tokens when they expire, and this results in the unhelpful "Unable to resolve AWS account to use" error.  See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/24744.

My aws sso config is structured like this:

```
# ~/.aws/config

[sso-session my_session]
sso_start_url = https://d-xxxxxxxxxx.awsapps.com/start
sso_region = us-east-1

# The default section is not strictly necessary, but it allows you to do 
# `aws sso login` without needing to specify `--profile`. Login is account
# independent, so it's fine to have a generic login and then use account
# specific profiles per command
[default]
sso_session = my_session

[profile profile_a]
sso_session = my_session
sso_account_id = 01234
sso_role_name = MyRole
region = us-east-1

[profile profile_b]
sso_session = my_session
sso_account_id = 56789
sso_role_name = MyRole
region = us-east-1
```